# Derivative of a function consisting of 2 functions.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've got a mock exam from a previous year with the following question:

> Suppose that we are given a pair of functions $g,h:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ satisfying the following properties:
>   $$g(0) = 2, h(0) = 1, g'(0) =−2, h'(0) = 1$$
>   and consider the function $k: \mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ defined as $k(t) = F(g(t), h(t))$.
>   What is $k'(0)?$

So I tried solving this using the chain rule, so:

$$k'(t) = F_x(g(t),h(t))g'(t) + F_y(g(t),h(t))h'(t)$$

$$k'(0) = F_x(g(0),h(0))g'(0) + F_y(g(0),h(0))h'(0)$$

$$k'(0) = F_x(2,1)(-2) + F_y(2,1)1$$

And now I'm stuck. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: What is $F{{}}$?

Comment: F is unkown, you only know g(0), h(0) and their derivatives at t = 0.

Comment: But it is a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: No, it is stated in the problem description that it goes from R to R.

Comment: Then $F(g(t),h(t))$ is not well-defined because $(g(t),h(t))\in\mathbb R^2$. Just to be clear: I am asking if $F$ is a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$

Comment: Ok so: Assuming that $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, then your solution is correct. Also, there is no further simplification: If you change $F$, then $k'(0)$ can also change

Comment: I unfortunately don't have any more information than the one I posted. That is literally the whole problem description.

Comment: Ok, I thought maybe I was missing something, but you agree with me that it doesn't appear to be more simplifyable than that?

Comment: Yes, I ${}$agree